# How can I find the type of CRL VOR at LTBU Corlu Ataturk airport? (Terminal,Low,High)

Tags: aeronautical-charts, vor, range

How can I find the type of CRL VOR at LTBU Corlu Ataturk airport? (Terminal, Low, High) Although there are reference documents for the FAA, I could not find a document for ICAO with the types of VOR stations on the Jeppesen charts. As an example, I am asking about CRL VOR at LTBU Corlu Ataturk airport.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can find such information in the **AIP (Aeronautical Information Publication)** of the country that operates the radio navigation aid. In section GEN 2.5 you will find a list of radio navigation aids. In section ENR 4.1 you will find more details for the en-route radio navigation aids.

In this case, you can find the overview list in the [Turkish AIP](https://www.dhmi.gov.tr/Sayfalar/aipturkey.aspx) (on the left select AIP > GEN > GEN2 > GEN 2.5):

[image: GEN 2.5]
<sup>(cropped from PDF)</sup>

The purpose can be **E** for en-route, **A** for aerodrome and **AE** for dual purpose. The CORLU VOR is therefore used for both en-route navigation and for the aerodrome (LTBU). As far as I know, there is no general distinction between low or high VORs, only en-route and terminal/aerodrome (the low and high distinction might be an American thing, see also [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/26030/how-do-you-know-if-a-vor-is-high-low-or-terminal)).

More details are given in ENR 4.1, but unfortunately the Turkish AIP does not allow access to the ENR section without registration and payment (same for the AD section where details for each aerodrome can be found). Here is an example from the [Austrian eAIP](https://eaip.austrocontrol.at/lo/210716/enr_4.htm) for detailed VOR information:

[image: FMD VOR]
<sup>([ENR 4.1 RADIO NAVIGATION AIDS - EN-ROUTE](https://eaip.austrocontrol.at/lo/210716/PART_2/LO_ENR_4_1_en.pdf))</sup>

The last column shows the coverage information for the VOR, which would make this something in between a low and high altitude VOR in the US (based on the definitions in [this article](https://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/navigation/the-types-of-vors-and-how-to-identify-them/)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the AIP section doesn't specifically mention terminal, low or high, right? Because I couldn't find it in the table on the AIP page that I added with the edit. I think we just evaluate the range of coverage in the remarks section and decide whether it is terminal, low or high accordingly, right?...

Comment: ...According to this situation, is it possible to say "HIGH VOR" because 75 NM coverage is more than 40 NM? Or we are not sure that it is high, but should we say "between a low and high altitude VOR" as in the example you gave from Austrian eAIP because it is more than low VOR's range? @Bianfable

Comment: @pilot162 A terminal VOR would correspond to an **A** entry in the purpose (aerodrome only). For **E** or **AE**, the VOR is also used en-route, but AFAIK there is no definition for low or high VOR outside the US. The 75NM coverage is *not* enough for a high altitude VOR in the US (requires up to 130NM for some altitudes, see linked article). So I would call CRL something in between.

Comment: Yes, as you said, I saw the range values that should be at different altitudes. For this reason, as you stated, it would be the most logical approach to say that it is between low and high. Thank you very much for your answer and reply!