# I have looked on the Low altitude IFR chart for this information and can not find it listed

Tags: aeronautical-charts

Inside the communications box after the name, what does (H), (H)(H), (L)(H), mean?

Comment: [How do you know if a VOR is High, Low, or Terminal?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/26030/3201)

Answer (score 2):

These are Standard Service Volumes, that denote how from how far away and how far up you can receive the navigational signal. (T) for terminal, (L) for low, and (H) for high.

There are also new service volumes, DL, DH, VL, and VH. You can find the exact definitions in the Chart Users' Guide, under "NAVAID STANDARD SERVICE VOLUME (SSV) CLASSIFICATIONS." As of October 5, 2023, it's on page 64.

For a combined navaid like a VORTAC, these service volumes don't need to be the same. The first listed is the VOR component and the second listed is the other component (e.g. DME for a VOR/DME).