# What is the radius of a VOR compass rose on a VFR sectional chart?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

I thought I read somewhere that it was 10 nautical miles. Does anyone have a reference on whether that's the case or not?

I'd like to use the measurement of a compass rose to aid in my estimation of how far away I might be from something else.

Answer (score 2):

I measured one on a sectional and it came out to approximately 19.4 NM. However, as mentioned, I'm not sure it has a fixed size. Symbols on a map can be resized by the cartographers (map makers) for ease of reading. I would not rely on this for anything other than trivia.

Answer (score 1):

https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/24044/3159 suggests that the rose can be printed in a reduced size in congested areas, so it is not guaranteed to be a particular size.  Unfortunately I can't find the current copy of the specifications on the FAA site either through existing links or searching....

That said, the size mentioned in the quote (.75" in diameter) appears to be about a quarter of the size printed on a sectional.  So perhaps this is talking about another product.